# Is it feasible to do random cropping as a data augmentation technique in the context of multi-label image classification?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, kaggle, data-augmentation

I have read 2 top-ranking solutions in kaggle concerning **multi-label image classification**. In both of the competitions I read, random cropping was performed. To me, this seems like a bad move to make because we could have a mismatch between the labels and the cropped images. Here are the **two links**:

1.[human-protein-atlas-image-classification](https://www.kaggle.com/c/human-protein-atlas-image-classification/discussion/78109#458525)

2.[iMet Collection 2019 - FGVC6](https://www.kaggle.com/c/imet-2019-fgvc6/discussion/94687#latest-672034)

If the reason for cropping is an input size image constraint for the used model architecture, then isn't it better to resize the image instead of cropping it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't visited the links yet, but random crop helps as long as you can keep the presence of classes, even only a small part of the actual object.